# keras dense input layer

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I am mainly a caffe user, I wonder how can I input my color image in a fully connected layer and then flatten it ( I know this is not the best solution but I need it).
This is a sample that is not working:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1000, input_shape=(img_channels, img_rows, img_cols)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
```

Any suggestion? I think I have to set the input layer and then flatten it but I don't know how.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Just found the solution...

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(img_channels, img_rows, img_cols)))
model.add(Dense(1000))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
```

It was obvious though. :(